# How to create DLLMain in C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a `DLL` in `C#` but I need to know what's the main method name called when the `DLL` is injected into a certain process.

For example, the `DLLMain` in `C++`.

Comment: No such thing exists.

Comment: Also note, that arguably, most uses of `DllMain()` (due to the loader lock issue) are [flawed](http://www.voyce.com/index.php/2009/12/03/dont-do-anything-in-dllmain-please/) or [dangerous](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/28/63880.aspx) anyway. Maybe you want to tell us what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: well , I'm trying to attach a dll to a process and the dll is doing a routine of checking some files if they exists etc.., and I guess the dll should have a main method where is executing the code

Comment: And you need to do that at the point the assembly is loaded? Would it be OK when you first use the relevant class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this even though it is 4 years old, so that there is a proper answer.

While you can used unmanaged DLLs in .NET using P/Invoke, .NET DLLs are managed DLLs an *can not* be used in unmanaged environments by using `LoadLibrary` or similar calls. There is really no way of simply providing the usual DLL functions and then using it from Delphi, C++ or the like.

What you *can* do is create a COM-DLL. That's pretty easy in .NET and after registering the DLL you can use the classes defined within the DLL from other languages using COM.

You could also try to create a wrapper DLL using C++ mixed mode, but I've not done this so far, as I'm not very much into C++. You might be able to use the unmanaged part from your unmanaged application and have it call the managed part.